# The best way to test responsive design for mobile?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Is there a way to test responsive of a web page, except google chrome device toolbar? I am asking this, because google chrome doesn't show the actual state. I set the same dimensions as i have on my smart, and it is different on chrome. Maybe use some emulator?

Comment: Browserstack - lets you test websites on virtual devices / browsers. Not sure what their free plan is like though.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en

Comment: @Satif they don't have latest smartphones and it works really bad

Comment: Then you need to install Android Studio or XCode and use their native emulators

Comment: But I don't see a problem with using chrome dev tools. Just use device toolbar and add custom device

Comment: @Satif as i said, although i added dimensions of my smartphone, chrome and samsung mobile have different results....

Comment: If you'd like for us to help you solve your issue, we need a minimal reproduction of the issue that's causing the problem; and screenshots would help. I recommend a reduced CSS and HTML page that reproduces the issue you're seeing, along with screenshots.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Isn't it clear enough?  I want to change responsive design for mobiles. And the chrome tool shows wrong result with the same resolution of my smartphone. I described it at least once before. Why would you need screenshot, if i ask for a better way to test actual mobile devices resolution?